# cannot connect to x server : running gui without displaying

Tags: cloud, ubuntu-14.04, xserver

I have a ubuntu server in which the requests are to be processed by a complex application in the backend involving a gui. The gui is of no use to me and only the final results are used and stored.

I get this error when launching the app **cannot connect to X server**
**How do i run a gui application on my linux instance without having me to actually see it**

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using vncserver, which creates an X display which your application can use, but keeps it "invisible" unless you connect to it using a VNC client. In my case, I have used the tigervnc-server package on RedHat Linux, but there must be a package for Ubuntu as well. Once you have it installed, you can start the X display with something like this:

```
vncserver :12 -geometry 1920x1200
```

You can adjust both the display number and the geometry to suit your taste and the needs of the application (by default you get a very low-res display). Once the VNC server is running, you need to figure out how to tell your application to use it. Most applications should respect the `$DISPLAY` environment variable, others have dedicated command options (e.g. firefox has a `--display` option). If you are happy doing it manually, just open the VNC display using a VNC client and start your application from there.

Note: you should also set a password for the VNC session using the `vncpasswd` command, and ideally block remote connections to the VNC session port.